# Probability of selecting positive integer with odd number of digits (Grinstead and Snell Ch 1.2 Q 28 (d))

Tags: probability, limits

If $A$ is the set of all positive integers with an odd number of digits, let $A\,(N)$ be the number of elements of $A$ which are less than or equal to $N$. Show that $P\,(A) = \lim_{N\to\infty} A\,(N)/N$ does not exist.

My rusty knowledge of limits says $P\,(A) = 0$, since the denominator dominates. Any help?

Comment: Why do you think the denominator dominates?

Comment: Just an intuitive guess. The difference between $A\,(N)$ and $N$ increases as $N$ increases.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you look at the beginning of the even set with $N_k=10^{2k+1}$ where k is an Integer then the last $10^{2k+1}-10^{2k}$ have been elements with an odd number of digits. Therefore we get $P(N_k) = A(N_k)/N_k \geq \frac{10^{2k+1}-10^{2k}}{10^{2k+1}}  $ which goes to 0.9 for k to infinity. But we can also look at the $M_k=10^{2k}$. For this we can show that $P(M_k)$ goes to 0.1 . Therefore the limit can‘t converge since we found 2 different  accumulation points.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure your answer is completely correct? but the principle makes sense. Is this standard methodology? i.e. is this method applicable to a large number of situations?

Comment: Proving something diverges  is normally (in a compact banach set) done by showing that there is more then one accumulation point. And this can be shown by finding a subsequence (existence of this is guaranteed due to the compact banach set) which converges to this accumulation point.

Comment: Could be that I made a mistake up there but I don‘t see it... which part, do you think is not correct and why?

Comment: $A(N)$ is the number of positive integers with an odd number of digits less than or equal to $N$. For what value of $k$ is $A(N_k)=10^{2k}-10^{2k-1}-1$? e.g. If $k=1$, $N_k = 100$ and $A\,(N_k) = 10$, $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,100\}$ but your definition gives 89.

Comment: Ups yes I see what you mean. I switched the even and odd case. I am correcting it now

Comment: Now it should work: k=1 => $N_k=10$, there are 9 single digit numbers, which is the value we estimated as a lower bound. For k=2 => $N_k=1000$ and there are 900 numbers with exactly three digits (in addition to the single digits) so the lower bound of 900 is correct as well.

Comment: This has the right idea, but it's wrong. The lim sup isn't 1, and the thing you claimed goes to 1 clearly equals $\frac{9}{10}$ and therefore can't possibly go to 1.

Comment: Seems like I was inattentive there.. doesn‘t matter the proof works with 0.9 and 0.1 as well. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 2):

*Hint*:

Compute $A(10^{2n})/10^{2n}$ and $A(10^{2n+1})/10^{2n+1}$.